# use jquery addclass and removeclass

Tags: jquery

i am making a lightbox code which requires me to use jquery `addClass` and i also require to use `removeClass` but i am not able to do that . my code is

```
      var d = this.buttons;
        if (c("body").find("#lightbox-buttons").length < 1) {
            this.list = c(a.template || this.template).addClass(a.position || "top").prependTo(g.utility.find("> div"));
            d = {
                prev: this.list.find(".btnPrev").click(g.prev),
                next: this.list.find(".btnNext").click(g.next),
                play_fast: this.list.find(".btnFast").click(g.play_fast).addClass(g.player_fast.isActive ? "btnPlayOn" : "")
            }
```

like in this line i also need to use removeClass to remove a class from one more button.

`play_fast: this.list.find(".btnFast").click(g.play_fast).addClass(g.player_fast.isActive ? "btnPlayOn" : "")`

Comment: i think anyone who down votes should atleast tell the reason . I had a problem for whom i thought i could share and get some help . But it downvote is the solution why would people start sharing thier problems on stack ?

Comment: Why can't you just add ".removeClass('classToRemove')" after the call to "addClass"?

Comment: cause i tried it its not working and also i have to remove a class of some different button not of the clicked button

Comment: Did you verify in Firebug or similar developer tools that the class wasn't being removed? Because it really should work...maybe there was a typo in the class name you were trying to remove, or maybe it did remove it but that didn't have the result you expected.

Comment: see the onclick event is on `.btnFast` and i needed to add class on that button but at the same time when person clicks on `.btnFast` i wan to remove `active` class from `.btnclose` . so i just cant add removeclass after addclass because it would try to remove active class from 'btnfast' not 'btnclose'

Comment: Btw why are you setting "d" to "this.buttons" and never using it (later you just assign d to something else)

Comment: i am using it its just a part of the whole lightbox i am making

Comment: I think the below answer should help you, ignore what I said about just adding ".removeClass" to the end of what you had (since you need to do it for a different element). As to the assignment of "d", lightbox or no, you could change "var d = this.buttons" to "var d;" and it would work exactly the same; there's no point in assigning it to this.buttons since you just reassign it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
var d;
if (c("body").find("#lightbox-buttons").length < 1) {
    this.list = c(a.template || this.template).addClass(a.position || "top").prependTo(g.utility.find("> div"));
    d = {
        prev: this.list.find(".btnPrev").click(g.prev),
        next: this.list.find(".btnNext").click(g.next),
        play_fast: this.list.find(".btnFast").click(g.play_fast).addClass(g.player_fast.isActive ? "btnPlayOn" : "")
    };
    //this assumes that the buttons you need to remove the class from all have the same class, in this example 'btnToRemoveClassFrom'
    this.list.find('.btnToRemoveClassFrom').removeClass('classToRemove');
}
```

Or if the button(s) you need to remove the class from aren't in the list, the last line would be simply:

```
c('.btnToRemoveClassFrom').removeClass('classToRemove');
```

To check for the existence of the `btnPlayOn` class first, as described in the comments, use:

```
if (this.list.find('.btnPlayOn').length > 0) {
    c('.btnToRemoveClassFrom').removeClass('classToRemove');
}
```

BTW, why on earth is `c` being used as the shorthand variable for jQuery? There are plenty of situations where it makes sense to make it something other than `$` but at least pick `$j` or something that remotely makes sense.

Edit: I think this version is a little more readable:

```
var d;
if (c("body").find("#lightbox-buttons").length < 1) {
    this.list = c(a.template || this.template).addClass(a.position || "top").prependTo(g.utility.find("> div"));
    var btnFast = this.list.find(".btnFast");
    d = {
        prev: this.list.find(".btnPrev").click(g.prev),
        next: this.list.find(".btnNext").click(g.next),
        play_fast: btnFast.click(g.play_fast)
    };

    btnFast.addClass(g.player_fast.isActive ? "btnPlayOn" : "");
    //this assumes that the buttons you need to remove the class from all have the same class, in this example 'btnToRemoveClassFrom'

    if (this.list.find('.btnPlayOn').length > 0) {
        this.list.find('.btnToRemoveClassFrom').removeClass('classToRemove');
    }
}
```

Comment: its removing the class as soon as i open the lightbox this should not happen . it should sustain the remove after i click once on play button

Comment: Maybe you need to check `g.player_fast.isActive` like you're doing with addClass? e.g. `removeClass(g.player_fast.isActive ? 'classToRemove': '')`? It's hard to know without knowing what lightbox plugin you're using.

Comment: Earlier you said "i want to btnStop-active class to be removed right away . not when the button is clicked." Now I'm confused.

Comment: i have a idea is there any way we can check if `btnPlayOn`class exist if it does we can say it to remove 'btnStop-active' else we wont remove it

Comment: Sure...either use `hasClass` if you have some other way of selecting the elements that you want to check for the class `btnPlayOn`, or if they're part of `this.list` then you could do `if (this.list.find('.btnPlayOn').length > 0)`

Comment: damn . Thanks @Matt this works. its the perfect solution :) please add this as an answer ill accept it thanks a lot for the help

Comment: For future reference, all this back-and-forth to find out what your actual goal is, is why someone downvoted your question. Next time try to be more clear in the original question and include the code you used to attempt to fix the problem...in your original question you don't show any code that even attempts to call `removeClass`. jsFiddle.com is also useful to let people see and play around with your code.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
this.list.find(".btnFast").click(function() {
  g.play_fast(); 
  $('#el_id_here').removeClass('class_name_to_remove');
}).addClass(g.player_fast.isActive ? "btnPlayOn" : "");
```

or

```
this.list.find(".btnFast").click(function() {
  $('#el_id_here').removeClass('class_name_to_remove');
  g.play_fast(); 
}).addClass(g.player_fast.isActive ? "btnPlayOn" : "");
```

Comment: removeClass() with no class name selectors should remove all classes. Try that and check with FireBug to make sure that is working first.

Comment: Looks like you're using the variable "c" to reference jQuery rather than the standard $, for what reason I don't know...so either use "c" or "jQuery" instead of "$".

Comment: yes i tried using like this `c('.btnStop').removeClass('btnStop-active');` its not removing the class :( i am stuck bad at this

Comment: @ParamVeer in your example you're adding the class right away, not when the button is clicked. Were you expecting the btnStop-active class to also be removed right away? Because this code will only remove it when the button is clicked. I think that's what you want in spite of your original code, just making sure...

Comment: i want to btnStop-active class to be removed right away . not when the button is clicked.

Comment: > giving a $ error means that jQuery is missing

Comment: @i100 not necessarily...in his case it appears that jQuery.noConflict was called and the variable `c` is being used to refer to jQuery (rather than `$`).